What is $E\left(\int_0^\infty E[T\mid T\ge t, L] \, dt\right)=$?
Let $T$ be a nonnegative absolutely continuous random variable, and $L$ be an arbitrary random variable. As the title states, is the quantity $E\left(\int_0^\infty E[T\mid T\ge t, L] \, dt\right)$ equal to something meaningful? I'm mostly curious about how it compares with quantities relates $E[T]$.
(For background of this question, including how it relates to the martingale theory, please see the bottom of the question.)
Here is what I have tried: Let $F_{T\mid L}(\cdot \mid L) = P(T\le \cdot\mid L)$ be the conditional CDF of T given $L$.
\begin{align*}
E\left(\int_0^\infty E[T\mid T\ge t, L] \, dt \right) &= E\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{\int_t^{\infty} v\, dF_{T\mid L}(v\mid L)}{1-F_{T\mid L}(t\mid L)}\,dt\right),
\end{align*}
But I don't have any intuition how to continue. If the computation is complicated, may I ask what would be a good interpretation on this quantity.
Eventually, I want to understand the following ''difference'' quantity and seek for any intuitive meaning:
$$
E\left(\int_0^\infty \{T - E[T\mid T\ge t, L]\} \, dt \right).
$$
I do understand that it equals $E\left(\int_0^\infty T \, dt\right) - E\left(\int_0^\infty E[T\mid T\ge t, L] \, dt \right)$, where the first term is just equal to $\infty$, but I'm still hoping there is an interpretation on the ''difference'' quantity.

Update thoughts: I think the question relates to the martingale theory.
Define $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma\{I(T\ge t), L \}$. Denote $H(t) = E[T\mid T\ge t, L]$. Then the stochastic process $\{H(t),t\ge 0\}$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$. Moreover, with fixed $t$, observe
\begin{equation}
E\{H(t)\} = E\left[ E\{H(t)\mid \mathcal{F}_{t}\}\right] = E\left[ E\{H(0)\}\right]= E\left\{ E(T\mid L) \right\}=  E(T).
\end{equation}
This implies that the martingale $\{H(t), t\ge 0\}$ has constant mean $E(T)$ over time. To that end,
\begin{align*}
E\left(\int_0^\infty \{T - E[T\mid T\ge t, L]\} \, dt \right)&= \int_0^\infty E\left( T - E[T\mid T\ge t, L]\right)\, dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \{E(T) - E(E[T\mid T\ge t, L])\}\, dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty 0\, dt\\
&= 0 ,
\end{align*}
where the second last line holds because the observation that the martingale $\{H(t), t\ge 0\}$ has constant mean $E(T)$ over time, i.e. $E(E[T\mid T\ge t, L])=E[T]$.

P.S. If it helps, there is some context of the this question. I now use the letter $T$ through out the question, one can think it represents the event time. For example, the event could be defined as the death from a surgery.
Here is the explanation on the conditioning part $T>t$, given in the comment of this post:

Note that conditioning on the event $\{\omega: T(\omega) \geq t\}$ does not make sense in rigorous measure theocratic terms. Only conditioning on $I(T \geq t)$, in the sense that you are conditioning on the sigma algebra generated by $I(T \geq t)$.

In other words, consider the quantity $E[T\mid T\ge t, L]$ as the conditional expectation of $T$ onto the sigma algebra generated by $I(T \geq t)$ and $L$.

What does it mean to condition on both a random variable and an event? Can you add a definition for your integrand as I don't think it's widely understood what it means.

I now realize what the question is asking. I initially added conditioning on $L$ due to the context—since patients have certain covariates measured, we typically work with conditional expectations given those covariates. However, upon further reflection, it seems that including $L$ in my original question may not be necessary.

Who knows what may or may not. A mathematical formulation can only be as good as the specification of the real-life problem it formulates. What on earth are "covariates"? Why you iterate expectations and need that $dt$ integral? Don't go into such an auto-pilot mode before you haven't bettter described what you do practcally in plain English. Brainstorming about martingales does't make it any better.

You have not really addressed Wei's question what it means to condition on both, the event $\{T\ge t\}$ and the random variable $L\,.$
Let's give that a go. If $\mathbb P$ is the unconditioned probability measure we start with and $\{T\ge t\}$ the event then
$$
\mathbb Q_t(A):=\mathbb P\{A|T\ge t\}=\frac{\mathbb P(A\cap\{T\ge t\})}{\mathbb P\{T\ge t\}}
$$
is a $t$-dependent probability measure having zero probability outside $\{T\ge t\}\,.$
A reasonable interpretation of your $E[X|T\ge t,L]$ is that this is
$$
\mathbb E_{\mathbb Q_t}\big[X\big|L\big]=\frac{\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[X1_{\{T\ge t \}}|L]}{\mathbb P\{T\ge t\}}\,.
$$
Then the expectation in your title is
\begin{align}
\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}\left[\int_0^\infty\mathbb E_{\mathbb Q_t}\big[X\big|L\big]\,dt\right]\stackrel{Fubini}=\int_0^\infty\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}\left[\frac{\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[X1_{\{T\ge t \}}|L]}{\mathbb P\{T\ge t\}}\right]\,dt\,.
\end{align}
By the tower property this is
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[X1_{\{T\ge t \}}]}{\mathbb P\{T\ge t\}}\,dt=\int_0^\infty\mathbb E_{\mathbb Q_t}[X]\,dt\,.
\end{align}
I do not think that this can be further simplified.
